# How to download Azure blob asynchronously only if it exists - in one step?

Tags: stream, async-await, azure-storage

I want to asynchronously download a block blob from Azure storage, but only if the blob exists.

```csharp
var blob = documentsContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
if (await blob.ExistsAsync())
    await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
```

But this makes two HTTP calls, right?  The common path in my app is that the blob will exist, so most of the time I don't want the overhead of the existence check.  But I need to gracefully handle the case where the blob doesn't exist also.

I tried leaving the existence check out and just using a try/catch block.  That works if I am using `DownloadTextAsync`, but when using `DownloadToStreamAsync`, if the blob isn't there, it just hangs.

Is there a way to download a binary blob to a stream asynchronously, only if it exists, without making two calls?

Comment: The lack of exception from `DownloadToStreamAsync` sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: DownloadToStreamAsync should throw an exception if it does not exist. Which version of the Windows Azure Storage Client Library are you using and which environment are you developing your application on?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that it *does* properly throw the exception:

```csharp
try
{
    var blob = documentsContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
    await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
    ...
}
catch (StorageException ex)
{
    if ((HttpStatusCode)ex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        return null;  // exit the calling function
    }

    throw;
}
```

When I tried this originally, it hung at the `DownloadToStreamAsync` call.  After the comments in the original question, I started checking the versions, and I found a mismatch in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll.  I was using 5.6.1, but my test project somehow had 5.6.0. (I'm not sure where it pulled that from, as it's not in my solution at all).  After manually referencing Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.1 from the test project, it no longer hangs.